# Trying to replace an existing Entity object with another in Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using Core Data for storage in my application, and within the application, there will be occasions where my "entities" will be modified (e.g. address, city, jobTitle).

Rather than updating a particular attribute of the entity, I would like to simply the process by creating a method where I replace the existing entity in storage with a newer version of the same entity (nothing fancy).  In my method, I figure I will have to fetch the required entity, but how do I actually do the replacement?  This is where I am confused.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    -(void)updateUser:(User *)user {

        // Create fetch request
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Create predicate
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@", user.userid];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

        // Create fetched results controller
        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil]; 
        self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = (id)self;

        //what do I do next? 

        NSError *error;

        if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

   }
```

As I said, I just simply want to replace the existing entity, with the newer one.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that replacing an object is simpler than changing an attribute.

But to do what you want, you would need code like this:

```
// I don't know the class for YourEntity, 
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle fetch error
} else {
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    YourEntity *newEntity = [[YourEntity alloc] initWithEntityDescription:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    // change settings on 'newEntity'

    for (YourEntity *recordToDelete in results) {
        [_managedObjectContext deleteItem:recordToDelete];
    }
    [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        // handle save error
    }
}
```